# Disabling clicks on whole page when spinner is displayed in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, z-index, event-loop

I am not able to disable mouse clicks everywhere on page when spinner is clicked.
Here is hierarchy of components with angular. There are child components in content-wrapper that should be able to call spinnner service.

```
// spinner.service.ts
  numberOfTasks: 0;
  spinnerSubject: any;
  spinnerState: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.spinnerSubject = new BehaviorSubject({ numberOfTasks: 0 });
    const spinnerShow = this.spinnerSubject.pipe(filter(state =>
      state.numberOfTasks > 0),
        mergeMap((state) => of(state).pipe(
        delay(state.delay),
        takeUntil(spinnerHide))));
    const spinnerHide =
    this.spinnerSubject.pipe(filter(state => state.numberOfTasks <= 0);
    this.spinnerState = merge(spinnerShow, spinnerHide); 
      )

  }

  show(delay) {
    this.spinnerSubject.next({ delay, numberOfTasks: ++this.numberOfTasks })
  }

  hide() {
    if (this.numberOfTasks > 0) {
      this.spinnerSubject.next({ numberOfTasks: --this.numberOfTasks });
    }

    // app.component.html
    <content-wrapper></content-wrapper>
    <page-spinner></page-spinner>

      page.spinner.html
       <div *ngIf="showSpinner" class="page-spinner">
           //  svg right here
        </div>
     //page-spinner.component.ts
     ngOnInit() {
       this.spinnerState.subscribe(state => { 
         this.showSpinner = state.numberOfTasks > 0;
         }
     })
     }
     // spinner.component.scss
    .page-spinner {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 999999;
      pointer-events:unset;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

I would like to notice that when I **hardcode the html of the spinner using developer tools**, so it is shown on the page I am not able to click on the page, but when spinner is loaded dynamically, as above, I still can click on buttons etc. even if spinner is shown. Please help me to find the root reason of this and help me fix this.

Comment: optional you can give the body element the style `pointer-events: none` for the spinner time and after the spinner back to `pointer-events: auto`

Comment: I tried to add a div wrapper in app.component  and tried to emit a showSpinner value from spinner component using EventEmitter, so that I can add this style to the wrapper but it didn't work it seems like the styles are applied too late or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable mouse clicks, you can add the following code to the body (or the parent element).

```css
element {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Add this to the body or to the elements individually. Then when the page has loaded, use some js to remove the CSS.

Comment: When spinner is hardcoded(shown always on the page) with pointer-events: none;  or pointer-events:  unset; like in my code in spinner.component.css above than I can't click, but I can click when spinner is added to DOM dynamically via ngIf directive and the thing is why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add debounceTime(300) to hideSpinner. Styles just didn't calculate fast enough.